# Probability that a graph of order $n$ has a subgraph which is a star of order $n$.

Tags: graph-theory, asymptotics, random-graphs

If a graph has $n$ vertices, is there a known expression for the probability that the graph will have as a subgraph a star with $n$ vertices? (I.e. if randomly sampled from the set of non-isomorphic graphs with $n$ vertices and any allowable number of edges).

Obviously, you can produce a not very tight bound using the probability of a graph being connected, but wondering if there were an exact known expression.

In particular if asymptotic results or exact results are known this would be great, but even good bounds would be interesting.

Comment: The topic of random graphs on $n$ vertices is often approached from giving each edge of complete graph $K_n $ a $0.5$ chance (independently sampled) of inclusion.  It isn't clear if you have a different notion for sampling a random graph.

Comment: I would mean more giving each graph with k vertices an equal chance of being sampled, not each edge, like using $G(n, m)$ but summing up over all m from 1 to k. Though if any expression for $G(n,p)$ exists that would also be of interest.

Comment: By $G(n,m)$ you mean(?) the number of non-isomorphic graphs with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges? Why would you sum "over all $m$ from $1$ to $k$"?

Comment: Oh I just mean you could think of it that way, because I realize sampling from non-isomorphic graphs with n vertices and any number of edges isn't as usual.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind.  Counting the number of non-isomorphic graphs with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges is really tough when $m$ is not tiny.  Possibly you saw that with fewer than $k-1$ edges we cannot have a star with $k$ vertices.

Comment: Sure what I mean is that if you had a large graph say, is there a way of knowing even using an asymptotic expansion what the probability is if you pick a graph from the space of all possible non-isomorphic graphs with equal probability with n vertices nand any number of edges in $[0, \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2})$, what the probability is that the graph contains a star with $n$ vertices as a subgraph? A simple lower bound is the probability of having more than $n$ edges, though this is not very tight.

Comment: Yeah, the non-isomorphic part makes this a really difficult question. No random graph sampling that I've ever encountered uses this condition, because (1) it doesn't model any real-world probabilities, (2) it is very very hard to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $k_m$ as the number of isomoprism classes of graphs on $m$ nodes.

Define $s_m$ as the number of isomorphism classes of graphs on $m$ nodes with a star, wi
th $s_0=0,s_1=1$.

Then $s_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (k_i-s_i)$.

This is seen by taking an isomorphism class of graphs with $i$ nodes and no stars, and adding $n-i$ stars.

Writing:

$$s_n = (k_{n-1}-s_{n-1})+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} (k_i-s_i) = k_{n-1}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} (k_i-s_i) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} (k_i-s_i)=k_{n-1}$$

So if you [know the sequence](https://oeis.org/A000088) $k_n$ your exact probability is $\frac{k_{n-1}}{k_n}$.

The non-isomorphic random graph sample is a highly unusual condition, because (1) it doesn't model any "real world" conditions, and (2) it tends to be very difficult.

From some of the [references here](https://oeis.org/A000088): $$k_m\sim \frac{2^{\binom m 2}}{m!},$$ then your probability is $\sim \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$.

---

If you abandon the non-isomorphic part, this is an inclusion-exclusion question.  If the nodes are $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, let $A_i$ be the number of graphs with a star at point $i$ - that is, where node $i$ is joined with all other nodes.

Then you want:

$$|A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots \cup A_n|$$

Inclusion-exclusion gives:

$$|A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots \cup A_n|=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}2^{\binom{n-k}2}$$

I doubt this has a nice cosed form.

Then the probability is this divided by $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$. You get the same asymptote $\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$.

This is also why we don't use the isomorphism classes when talking about random graphs. As $n$ gets large, "most" graphs have no automorphisms, so their isomorphism classes have $n!$ elements, and the asymptotes of probabilities tend to agree with the much simpler model of random graphs.

Comment: I have nothing to add except thankyou very much!